# Error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de subir videos usando laravel y me esta soltando ese error, aun poniendo el `{!! csrf_field() !!}` y `{{ csrf_token() }}` me sigue arrojando el error, tambien desactive en el kernel el `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`, y aqui succede algo curioso tambien, en el formulario tengo 2 validaciones requeridas para 2 campos y al enviar el formulario me da error que esos campos son requeridos aun cuando ya los llene.

Si quito la validacion de requeridos a estos campos, es la unica forma que se envie pero a a la `BBDD` no llega nada, si alguien sabe como puedo solucionar principalmente el error del `Token`.

**Vista**

```
@extends('layouts.app')    {{-- Plantilla maestra a utilizar --}}

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Crear un Nuevo Video</h2>
            <hr>

            <form action=" {{ route('saveVideo') }} " method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-lg-7">

                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                {!! csrf_field() !!}    <!-- Token de seguridad que laravel obliga a poner -->

                @if($errors->any())     <!-- Errores de validacion -->
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li> {{$error}} </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif

                {{-- old('name'), es un helper que si el formulario arroja un error le da el ultimo valor al campo definido con el helper --}}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Titulo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Descripción</label>
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="description">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Miniatura</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="video">Video</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Crear Video</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection´
```

**Controlador**

```
public function saveVideo(Request $request){

        // Validaciones del Formulario

            $validateData = $this->validate($request, [
                'title'       => 'required|min:5',
                'description' => 'required',
            ]);

        $video = new Video();   // Instanciamos el modelo creado
        $user = \Auth::user();  // Para conseguir el usuario identificado
        $video->user_id = $user->id;
        $video->title = $request->input('title');
        $video->description = $request->input('description');

        // Subida de la miniatura

            $image = $request->file('image');

            if($image){
                $image_path = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();  // Para obtener el nombre del fichero, se pone el time() para que guarde el tiempo en que se cargo la imagen de forma que nunca se repita el nombre
                \Storage::disk('images')->put($image_path, \File::get($image)); // Obtenemos el fichero a guardar

                $video->image = $image_path;
            }

        // Subida de el Video

            $video_file = $request->file('video');

            if($video_file){
                $video_path = time().$video_file->getClientOriginalName();
                \Storage::disk('videos')->put($video_path, \File::get($video_file));

                $video->video_path = $video_path;
            }

        $video->save();

        return redirect()->route('home')->with(array(
            'message' => 'El video se a subido correctamente'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Rutas**

```
// Rutas del controlador de Videos

    Route::get('/crear-video', array(
        'as'         => 'createVideo',  // Nombre de la ruta
        'middleware' => 'auth', // Middleware a usar
        'uses'       => 'VideoController@createVideo' // Que controlador y accion a usar
    ));

    Route::post('/guardar-video', array(
        'as'         => 'saveVideo',  // Nombre de la ruta, (PUEDE SER USADO EN LOS ACTION DE LOS FORM)
        'middleware' => 'auth', // Middleware a usar
        'uses'       => 'VideoController@saveVideo' // Que controlador y accion a usar
    ));
```

Comment: como estas usando forms, no deberia ser {{ csrf_field() }} sin los signos de admiración?

Comment: Eso tampoco funciona, sigue el mismo error

Comment: puedes agregar por favor el fragmento de código donde te esta indicando el error tambien?

Comment: Te refieres al codigo propio del framework?, porque como tal el error me lo arroja la parte del controlador donde intento cargar el video

Comment: te recomiendo borrar `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`, y solo quedarte con `{!! csrf_field() !!}`, ya que tecnicamente son lo mismo, posterior a eso seria bueno poder ver tus rutas...

Comment: Ya actualize con las rutas pana, y el `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` en realidad lo coloque ya que es parte de una solucion que dan en `stackoverflow en ingles`, pero de igual forma no me funciono

Comment: Tu usuario esta logeado al momento de subir el video?, por que si no lo esta no debes de utilizar el middleware 'auth'.

Comment: Si se encuentra logeado, justo lo tengo asi para que no deje subir sin un logeo previo

Comment: ingresa en tu consola de navegador y verifica que tu **token** este ahi. Tendria que existir una etiqueta igual a esta `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="29GqtiYxAibtyHLpr7gSu2VfGIgGVyYAQgldLpae">`, con el value diferente claro

Comment: ok, si me aparece

Comment: pues la ultima opcion seria insertar el token en la cabecera del html ej: `<html><head><meta name="csrf-token" content="29GqtiYxAibtyHLpr7gSu2VfGIgGVyYAQgldLpae"></head><body>codigo</body></html>`, ten en cuenta que aun asi el token debe de estar en tu fomulario.

Comment: Eso tambien lo intente hace rato y nada, lo puse asi `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`, me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, el problema como tal no era de codigo, si no del tamaño de subida, estaba intentando con un video de unos 20mb y mi `php.ini` deja un maximo de 2mb, con un video de ese tamaño no hay ningun problema